# Button Python Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, kivy

Как убрать смену цвета при нажатии на кнопку?Чтобы при нажатии, например,на серую кнопку,она не окрашивалась в голубоц и тд?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установить параметр у Button background_down равным параметру background_normal. Это соответственно фон нажатой кнопки и кнопки в обычном состоянии.

```
background_normal = StringProperty(
    'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/button')
    '''Background image of the button used for the default graphical
    representation when the button is not pressed.
    '''

background_down = StringProperty(
    'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/button_pressed)
'''Background image of the button used for the default graphical
representation when the button is pressed.
'''
```

Comment: NameError: Global name 'String Property' is not defined

Comment: Вообще то StringProperty нужно импортировать из модуля kivy.properties. И совсем не понятно, зачем вам StringProperty для того, чтобы установить значения параметров в Button. Код, который я привел в ответе - это кусок документации из kivy.uix.button.Button.Вообще, если бы вы посмотрели исходные тексты kivy, многие вопросы отпали бы сами собой, потому что kivy прекрасно документирован. Порою документации в исходниках больше, чем кода.